# How to track Azure web site backup progress?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I started a web site backup in the Azure Portal (under the BACKUPS tab). I get a pending operation in the notification field, it soon changes to
`"Successfully started backup for web site 'mywebsite1'.`
That's all very well. But when is it finished? How do I find out? Typically I would want to wait for this before doing any changes to the web site.

The same question goes for the corresponding restore operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find operation details (backup/restore) in operation logs. You can go there e.g. from the "dashboard" tab. There is a "management services" section on the right and right below there is a link called "operation logs".

For each operation you should see a start and en end. If you click on details, you will get more information and progress. However, you don't see the "end" record until the operation is done (no matter whether it succeeds or fails).

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it does help! Though for me, it's well-hidden in the left column where you select the different kind of services. Would you care to share a screen shot of your dashboard section? Are you using the old portal or the new?

Comment: I've added the screenshot. This is the old portal.